# Get length of wav file? (playing wav with soundplayer class)

Tags: c#, .net, wav, soundplayer

I'm playing wav sound files using the .NET `SoundPlayer` class in my program, is it somehow possible to get the length of the wav file (in milliseconds)?

Thanks for answers.